# Regex in java: error for str.replace("\s+", " ")

Tags: java, regex

Why the java (1.7) gives me error for the following line?

```
String str2 = str.replace("\s+", " ");
```

Error:

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

As far as I know "\s+" is a valid regex. Isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`String.replace()` will only replace literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), that's the first problem.

The second problem is that `\s` is not a valid escape sequence in a Java string literal, by definition.

Which means what you wanted was probably `"\\s+"`.

But even then, `.replace()` won't take that as a regex. You have to use `.replaceAll()` instead:

```
s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

BUT there is another problem. You seem to be using it often... Therefore, use a `Pattern` instead:

```
private static final Pattern SPACES = Pattern.compile("\\s+");

// In code...

SPACES.matcher(input).replaceAll("");
```

---

**FURTHER NOTES:**

- If what you want is to only replace *the first occurrence*, then use `.replaceFirst()`; `String` has it, and so does `Pattern`
- When you `.replace{First,All}()` on a `String`, *a new `Pattern` is recompiled for each and every invocation*. Use a `Pattern` if you have to do repetitive matches!

Answer (score 4):

[It's a valid regular expression pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), but `\s` is not a valid `String` literal [escape sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-EscapeSequence). Escape the `\`.

```
String str2 = str.replace("\\s+", " ");
```

As suggested, `String#replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` doesn't consider the arguments you provide as regular expressions. So even if you got the program to compile, it wouldn't do what you seem to want it to do. Check out `String#replaceAll(String, String)`.

Comment: Well, uh, there's another problem, isn't it? `.replace()` won't accept regexes, only literals...